# Preventing the spread of infection

Tags: divinity-original-sin

My Marksman recently got the Infect spellbook, and I tried it out on a battle with some melee Orcs. It ended up spreading to their entire team, then one of the Orcs ran over to us, and infected my entire team! I was under the impression it only spreads on the turn that it was cast.

This is obviously a problem, since making everyone (including my team) diseased isn't particularly useful.

Is Infect really only useful against enemies that are exclusively range-based? Is there a way to prevent it from spreading to my team, besides only using it against non-melee enemies, and avoiding melee attacks while they're infected?

Comment: Is this for original sin or original sin 2? Because in 1 Infect just plants diseased on one character whereas in 2 it sets an effect status that spreads to nearby characters

Comment: @n_palum 1, enhanced. And it does spread. As I mentioned, I watched it spread. This might have been a change in EE.

Comment: Ah probably an EE change, if that's the case I think your best bet is having high body building stats for the saving throw against it

Comment: @n_palum I was talking to my friend, and he suggested the same thing. Also said Ice Wall might be helpful if there's a choke point you can block. If you make up decent an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Infect gives diseased status to those affected, but it also has an infected property that lasts two turns as far as I know. If you come in close proximity to someone with the infect status, you can contract the affliction.

Your only saving throw for infect and diseased is '**bodybuilding**'. Increasing that stat is your best way of preventing it from spreading if they get too close to you.

Other options are to keep enemies you've infected away from your team. This could involve **using cc** in some fashion (freezing, slowing, stunning etc), putting **physical barriers** between you (ice walls, crates, frozen puddles, electrified clouds etc), or simply **teleporting** the infected enemy further away from you.

Ideally if you're infected an enemy you'd want to be **killing them off as quickly as possible** since diseased lowers their constitution (total HP). When disease ends, they'll get those stats back and their health will go back to normal.